# ¿Cómo hacer sinónimos en una base de datos?

Tags: mysql, select

Probablemente el título no ayude, pero me explico. Necesito hacer una búsqueda en mi base de datos, pero probablemente no tenga que ingresar exactamente como se encuentra en la base de datos.

> Ejemplo: Tengo mi tabla "preguntas" y una de mis preguntas es "¿Cómo
>   se llama el perro?" con un ID '1' pero yo ingreso en mi select "¿Cuál
>   es el nombre del perro?"

Es posible hacer eso y que apunte al ID indicado?.
Otro caso sería.

> Ejemplo: Tengo mi tabla "preguntas" y tengo la pregunta "No enciende
>   mi PC" con ID '1', pero en mi select ingreso "Mi PC no enciende" 
>   y que obtenga el ID indicado ('1')

Habría manera de reconocer eso?
o cual sería la forma de hacerlo?

Comment: con el operador `LIKE` sería una opción

Comment: Lo que estas pidiendo es un buscador semantico. Ninguna base de datos tiene eso por defecto, se necesitan algoritmos para igualar palabras. No es algo simple

Comment: Si tengo claro que no es algo simple, pero no sabía que se le denominaba "Buscador Semántico", empezaré por ahí, Gracias !!